# smallint always useful?

Tags: database

Do you think today, a **smallint** database type remains useful or is it like short on 32/64 bit CPU (better using **int**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this all depends on the underlying implementation of the RDBMS and processor architecture.  Depending on the particular architecture of a processor different primitive types could be handled differently and depends on that implementation (what functional units the processor contains for handling a particular case with a low number of clock cycles).  The bit width of any particular "type" is determined by the proc architecture, although the bus width is 32-bits (or 64) there's no need to use only 32 bit or multiples thereof in the data types.  From what I understand it will take a little more processing time to operate on the 2byte types since it will need to "mask the results" but you will save in terms of memory (optimization could be the need to reduce memory usage or CPU usage or disk access depending on your bottleneck, I get that memory is so cheap it's almost always better to sacrifice the cost there, but the point stands).  So in the case of a large amount of data like quadrillions of rows then the smaller data type is probably still a good thing to use, in the case of a DB that is doing a lot of processing on the records but without the space limitation issues it would probably be better to go with the type that fits the data and bus width.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you don't need to store numbers outside the range of smallint, then using int is just eating up space unnecessarily (4 bytes vs 2 bytes for smallint). Rule of thumb, go with the data type that best fits the scope of data it will contain. Along the same vein, in SQL Server world, is it a good idea to always use VARCHAR(MAX) instead of e.g. VARCHAR(100)? No.

Comment: Not really the same thing. With 32bit architecture CPU you can also use a short, but internally it is changed into 4bytes for performance reason...

Answer (score 1):

Unless space/rowsize/etc. is a critical consideration, I would never use a integral type smaller than a 32-bit int. You are almost guaranteed to have type conversion/overflow/underflow problems somewhere down the line. Further, systems are pretty highly optimized for 32-bit operations (your 16-bit or 8 bit integers are likely processed in 32-bit registers anyway).

At the same time, I probably wouldn't use a 64-bit integer unless I really needed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to make much difference from a performance standpoint, but unless you can absolutely guarantee that smallint will never be too small for your data, go with int: Space is cheap while data overflow errors in the field are not.

Comment: Space is cheap, but slow. A 10Gb database that fits in memory is an order of magnitude faster than a 20Gb database that does not fit in memory

Answer (score 0):

Let the database implementation worry about it.

**Noting/Hinting what kind of data is going to be stored at that field is always good**, it lets the SQL daemon take this into consideration when it tries to make the best for you.